# Approximation of general measures by finite measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{E})$ be any measurable space, $M := ca^+(E,\mathcal{E})$ be the set of all non-negative measures on $\mathcal{E}$ endowed with the $*$-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$, i.e. the coarsest $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ such that each map $\mu \to \mu(A)$ with $A \in \mathcal{E}$ is measurable. Let further $M_n := \{\mu \in M \colon \mu(E) \leq n\}$, endowed with the $*$-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}_n$. When is there a sequence $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathcal{M}/\mathcal{M}_n$-measurable maps $T_n \colon M \to M_n$ such that
$$\mu(A) = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} T_n(\mu)(A)$$
for all $A \in \mathcal{E}$? Is it even possible to find $T_n$ with $T_n(\mu) = \mu$ for $\mu \in M_n$?